# use iOS Simulator without code, use from usb flash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Can I take my iOS Simulator on usb flash and then use it from this flash or from other mac? I kept it from

```
Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
/Developer/Applications/Simulator iOS
```

I tried use it, but unfortunelly. I think I need something like library for him.
 I read that I can get my .app in iOS folder, where lie others apps for Simulator, and run it without my code. I can't find folder with Simulator apps even on my mac. In

```
...library/Application Support/
```

i haven't folder iOS Simulator. Where I can find simulator folder with applications, that runs on it?
I need it all because I must show my project for my teacher on his mac, but it always crashes on all macs except my mac. That's I need use my iOS simulator, I think

Comment: The iOS Simulator is primarily intended for testing apps prior to deploying them on a device. The applications it builds are not meant to be portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant just take your simulator and run it from USB flash drive. Probably you can install the Xcode in their Mac and then copy the app folder from `/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0` and paste it in their mac in the same folder.There should be a folder which looks like `0BE5QAF2-7F78-4C2B-BV5E-41212C635784` which is what you need to copy. Check inside that and see if you can find a .app file with your project name. After that you can open your app on the simulator in that mac. You dont need a code to run your app in that simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Like he said above the only solution would be to download xcode on the other mac and then copy your project over to that computer... Kind of a waste of time though..